# Skip certain words while reading text from a file using matlab

Tags: string, matlab, file-io, stop-words

I have created a matlab program to find word bigrams and their frequencies in a text file. For this purpose I have created a cell array of strings using textread function:

unigrams = textread('file.txt','%s');

But I also wish to omit a bunch of words like 'to', 'the', 'is', 'or', etc and special characters '#', '$', '&' and '%' from my cell array. Is there a way to exclude these words while reading the words from the raw file.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you would want to do it *while* reading the words from the file and not *after*? If not, see my answer below.

Comment: I recommend using Python for this, specifically NLTK.

Comment: @cyborg I agree...python is great for string handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setdiff` *after* reading the text to remove the unwanted words:

```
unigrams = {'I' 'like' 'this' 'or' 'that' 'Here' 'are' 'some' 'symbols' '#' '$' '&'}
setdiff(unigrams, {'the', 'is' 'or' '#' '$' '&'}, 'stable')

unigrams = 
  Columns 1 through 8
    'I'   'like'   'this'   'or'   'that'   'Here'   'are'   'some'
  Columns 9 through 12
    'symbols'   '#'   '$'   '&'
ans = 
    'I'   'like'   'this'   'that'   'Here'   'are'   'some'   'symbols'
```

Comment: I agree there are a bunch of easy ways to do this *after* reading. The OP wants to do it *while* reading though - although not sure why...

Comment: I do believe that performance will be increased  if the operation is executed **after** reading. This may not do it the way the poster asked, but it will achieve the same effect, assuming the entire file will fit into memory, that is.

Comment: I am already reading thousand of files to find the bigrams, which takes up a lot of time. So I just need the best performing method to exclude these words. The way suggested by Kavka works perfectly. If there is another better performing method to exclude the words while, before or after reading the files do tell me. @ cyborg I have never used Python, if there are better ways to do these codes in python could you please suggest where should I start from. @ all Thanks for helping.